# Is it possible to have different rules for main and test code?

Tags: scala, codacy

Is it possible to set different rules for main versus test code in Codacy? I know I can eliminate inspection of test code. But I don't want to do that. However, there are many rules, especially regarding duplication, that just don't make sense for tests.

My main language is Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The best you can do is ignore folders (for instance the test folder).

We typically relax on test code, but it makes sense to avoid duplication on test code as well. Your (real) code will evolve over time, and eventually will make you need to change tests. Why change in 100 places instead of a single method that is shared among several tests?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I agree about test code duplication, but wouldn't consider it quite such a "crime" as in main code ;)